# R ggplot2: Draw diagonal lines on log-scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I had a graph created with default R-plot functionality but now want to change to ggplot2 mainly because I want to use ggrepel to place labels correctly and non-overlapping.

My old plot contains diagonal lines which I need to keep. They are ploted like this:

```
for (i in -5:10) {
    abline(a= i, b= 1, lty = 5)
}
```

The issues I have now are:

1. How do I do this for-loop with ggplot2 so I don't need to add all the lines expliclty?
2. How do I actually created the lines correctly?

   ```
   geom_abline(slope=1, intercept=10)
   ```

Does not work as expected, probably due to log10 scale. So how can I draw diagonal lines on log10 scales correctly?

Comment: You can specify different values for slope writing `geom_abline(slope=(-5):(10), intercept=10)`.  If I have understood well, you have now 'log10` scale, so what you need to plot is not a line; it is a curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually works fine. This issue is directly related to my [other issue about x and y axis limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43731555/ggplot2-log10-scale-and-axis-limits/43731681#43731681). Per default the plot draws a bigger area than the x and y limits define (who thought this was a good idea???). And therefore the intercepts look wrong but the actually are ok.

If I set `expand = c(0, 0)` for both axis, then the intercept is also looks fine because that only draws to the limits.

The solution for multiple lines is a intercept list:

```
 geom_abline(slope=1, intercept=(-3):(5)
```